# How to fill a ByteArrayOutputStream with the content of a file?

Tags: java

I have File and need to fill its content to a ByteArrayOutputStream, can someone help me with that? With Google Guava I am able to create an ByteArray but how do I get an ByteArrayOutputStream from this?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
File img = new File("myTestfile.txt");
byte[] filesBytes = Files.toByteArray(f);

//does not work
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(filesBytes);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to read the file into a stream?

Comment: sure, but i just did not find a good link where i can understand the stream stuff

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) can be of help in Java 7.

   > Read all the bytes from a file. The method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime exception, is thrown.
   >
   > **Note that this method is intended for simple cases where it is convenient to read all bytes into a byte array. It is not intended for reading in large files.**
2. The more conventional way would be to use a `FileInputStream` and `read()` the file to a `byte[]`.
3. [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) has [byte[] org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) method.
4. [Google's Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) got [ByteStreams.toByteArray(InputStream)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) and [Files.toByteArray(File)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toByteArray%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 3):

Here's the old fashioned way to read from a file into a ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
public void getBytes(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            fileName));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bytes = 0;
    while ((bytes = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }
    baos.close();
    bis.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at Apache Commons IO (Library)'s method:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File, java.io.OutputStream)

Alternatively, you can use:

```
File f = new File("/location/of/my/file");
byte[] = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray(java.io.File)